# How to call function in AngularJS controller with $scope method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function inside my controller that I want to be able to call from a $scope method so I can reuse my code only within the controller. I use the function to clear some input fields. I would like to call after a user is inserted as well as I would like to assign it to the a "Clear" button click. Calling the function after inserting works just fine but assigning the function to the method isn't.

If I assign the function directly to the $scope.clearUser method it works but then I can't call it after inserting a user.

```
function clearUser() {
    $scope.EmployeeNumber = '';
    $scope.isAdmin = false;
};

$scope.clearUser = clearUser();    
//also tried $scope.clearUser = this.clearUser();

//$scope.clearUser = function() {
//    $scope.EmployeeNumber = '';
//    $scope.isAdmin = false;
//};

<button ng-click="clearUser()" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear
</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Omit the `()` to pass the function:

```
$scope.clearUser = clearUser;
```

Or, create it all at once:

```
var clearUser = $scope.clearUser = function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

$scope.clearUser = clearUser();

to

$scope.clearUser = clearUser;

Comment: Perfect! Removing the () worked. I would have never guessed to assign it that way. I would have thought it needed the () to let it know it was a function. Either way, I know for now on.Thanks for everyone's help!